# External Hard drive not recognized on Ubuntu server 20.04 lts. Linux mint 20 does see it

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive

I have a Seagate expansion 6tb external hard drive and have partitioned it into a 3tb ntfs and a 3tb ext4.  When I use my 3 linux mint 20 systems I have no issues seeing it with fdisk.  I wanted to use it as a network drive so I am in the process of setting up a server running 20.04.  When I attach the usb hard drive I can't find it when I run fdisk/lsusb to mount, just shows the internal hard drive partitions.

on the linux mint systems they are shown as /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: USB3? MBR vs GPT? Plugged into what port? Powered USB hub?

Comment: It is a USB3 connection from the drive(6tb drive- GPT) into the usb3 port a dell laptop.

Comment: Sounds correct. Are you using a real quality USB3 cable (with blue ends)?

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT model # of the Dell laptop.

Comment: Is the BIOS setting for USB set to legacy, or enable USB3 support?

Comment: Bios version A11.  Computer Dell Inspiron 5547.  USB3 cable not sure. Seagate indicates that it is USB3 does not have blue ends, just black. Bios boot is set to EUFI but legacy is enabled.  Tried turning legacy off but it wouldn't boot after that.  In Bios can't see anything that references USB3 specifically.

Comment: Linux mint machine-run fdisk -l with the hdd attached:   

Disk /dev/sdb: 5.47 TiB, 6001175125504 bytes, 11721045167 sectors
Disk model: Expansion Desk  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 918BD400-73FD-4733-A6B5-B45C68301116

Device          Start         End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048  5133819903 5133817856  2.4T Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb2  5133819904 11721043967 6587224064  3.1T Microsoft basic data

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Before doing anything else check that it is not a cable or voltage problem. I wasted a lot of time as my new external drive mounted on a Ubuntu 20.04/Windows computer but would not mount on other computers running Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 Solved when i identified a front panel USB port internal cable was too thin/long. On the other machine i had to connect to a rear usb port with a longer drive connecting cable. The symptoms had been a clicking noise from the drive and fdisk and gparted not finding the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

Dell Inspiron 5547

You have BIOS version A11, from 2/24/2018.

There's a newer BIOS available, version A13, from 9/24/2019, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-15-5547-laptop/drivers).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**USB3 external disk**

You're using an improper cable for USB3. Your cable has black ends. That's for USB2. USB3 cables have blue ends. Obtain the proper cable and retest. (Or, try plugging into a USB2 port on the computer and see if it works there with the black-ended cable.)

Comment: After I figured out how to update bios its appeared. Thanks

Comment: @Meteoman Great news! Thanks for the update.